# Git version one before latest version

Tags: git, shell, awk

I know how to receive the latest git version by using `git describe --tags --abbrev=0`. However in my special case I need the version ONE before.

If the latest version is `v0.0.3` I need to get `v0.0.2` for instance.

I tried to find a way to do so but my shell/git magic is weak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk` along with your `git` command could you please try following.

```
git describe --tags --abbrev=0 | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} {$NF-=1} 1'
```

***Explanation:*** Passing `git` command's output to `awk` command as an input. In `awk` code `BEGIN` section setting field separator and output field separator as `.` for all lines. Then in main program deceasing `1` in last field of current line. `1` is one of the ways in `awk` to print current line.

Answer (score 4):

```
git describe --tags --abbrev=0 HEAD^
```

The parent of the HEAD commit is HEAD^. Using `--abbrev=0` as you already were prevents the output of the sha as part of the description, so only printing the first found tag.

```
$ git log --oneline
63fbe99 (HEAD -> master, tag: v0.0.2) Add c
3de8c2c Add b
98b2cc4 (tag: v0.0.1) Add a
1fe3ea8 (tag: v0.0.0) Initial commit

$ git describe --tags --abbrev=0
v0.0.2

$ git describe --tags --abbrev=0 HEAD^
v0.0.1
```

Comment: for me nothing is changing:
```xetra11@pop-os:~/Development/projects/CK3-Workbench$ git describe --tags --abbrev=0 
0.0.14-alpha
xetra11@pop-os:~/Development/projects/CK3-Workbench$ git describe --tags --abbrev=0 HEAD^
0.0.14-alpha
```

Comment: `git describe --tags --abbrev=0 v0.0.3~`